# Redirect User's to an error page!

Tags: customer, store-view

Hello Magento Community!
I currently check customers for their Browser / Operating System to see if it is compatible with our website. (Ex Windows XP is no longer supported by Microsoft or many main web browsers)

How can I make it so that when people first come to my website I perform the check then redirect them to an error page, or possibly a customizable view with error messages? Is it possible to do without creating custom blocks or controllers?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache then you could consider setting up a rewrite with the condition checking `HTTP_USER_AGENT`. This will allow you to redirect different users to different pages.